# How to make div containers arch?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get make a webpage where each div container arches. I have tried radial-gradient but can't seem to make it work. The image below is what I want to accomplish where each color is it's own div container

[image]

Comment: Can you put some code so we can understand what are you trying to get.

Comment: check out this. this may helpfull for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67144321/how-would-i-create-an-arch-of-images-in-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using **border-bottom-left-radius: ;** **border-bottom-right-radius: ;** for your div you can make arch div.

check this link https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-wilson-te1kwe?file=/index.html I developed your requirement. I think it will help you to get an idea.